# Installing Matlab from ISO

Tags: 14.04, matlab

I am very new to Ubuntu.

I am trying to install matlab using the steps found here (From and ISO file)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

But when I use sudo ./install I get this error

```
chris@chris-ThinkPad-X301:/media/chris/MATHWORKS_R2015a$ sudo ./install


/media/chris/MATHWORKS_R2015a/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: 1: 
/media/chris/MATHWORKS_R2015a/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

I am totally baffled whats wrong.  How is there a Syntax error with ")" when I am not even using a ")"?

Answer (score 0):

The file `install` is a script which invokes `install_unix`

The error message you get is because there is a programming error in `install_unix`

I know this is not a solution to your problem.

But it is an answer to your question.

Comment: Not an solution but helpful. Thank you!